# Redirect cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Montei uma action, em que, ao clicar em um ícone na página, ele chama essa action e na própria tem um redirect para a própria página. O problema é que não está fazendo esse redirect.

Action:

```
public function limpar_criterios(){
    return $this->redirect('/intercambio/pesquisa_nova');
}
```

Link que faz a call:

```
<a href="/limpar_criterios/inglês"><img src='/img/bandeiras/small_45x31_1.jpg' width="39" height="31" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema do seu link, é que o controlador é **limpar_criterios** e a action é **inglês** quando na verdade o **limpar_criterios** é a action. Obs.: procura não utilizar acentos em url's.

Cria o link usando o [HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) do CakePHP:

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('bandeiras/small_45x31_1.jpg', 
        array(
            'alt' => 'Imagem',
            'width' => '39',
            'height' => '31'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'controller' => 'NOME_DO_CONTROLADOR',
        'action' => 'limpar_criterios'
    ),
    array('escape' => false)
);
```